# Reminder in GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am doing an project on *Java* and *GWT* and stuck in one part I want to create a reminder that is like user enters date and time and at that time a pop up should be displayed reminding user of his event. Can anyone suggest me any approach towards achieving this.

When I googled for the solution i found some stuff related to **timers** in *GWT* but I guess timer has method `schedule()` which takes milliseconds as parameter but converting date and time into milliseconds doesn't seem the solution so any other alternative is highly appreciated.

Comment: +1 for question. It might be a fundamental problem if you need to sync up with server for new remainders ( http and async means timer based polling rpc requests to server ) or am i imagining dragons....

Comment: @Durrat, you say "converting date and time into milliseconds doesn't seem the solution". Why not? That'd be a simple client-side only solution. Hence, if the user closes the app the reminder is gone. You could, however, persist it in the browser using a cookie.

If you really, really need a solution that involves the server I suggest you look into GwtEventService as suggested by 'mudalov'.

Answer (score 4):

You can't handle it with only timers. Seems that you need to implement some server side logic to achieve this.

1. User select time and date for event on *client* -> call to *server* to store it somewhere (could be simple RPC or Ajax call)
2. Notifying the user could be achieved by several ways:

   - `Simple polling` - ask *server* from *client* what events happened since last check every N (let't say 10) seconds, using Ajax calls. Server needs to compare current time and send events list back to the client
   - `Long poll` or `Hidden Iframe` to be used for pushing the events to the client - more complex, but also could be implemented

You can also take a look at [GwtEventService](https://code.google.com/p/gwteventservice/) to manage your events between *server* and *client*.

Finally your logic stays simple - *client* needs to listen from the *server* about **happened events** and to show pop up dialog in the handler.

Comment: Change - pooling to polling ( stackoveflow wont allow me to edit when change is less than 6 chars )

Comment: hey marcel thanx..i thought converting date and time into msec is not standard way and when my event is created it is saved in a file on server so i dnt really need server involvement so i will calculate msec and get my stuff done...thanx...

Comment: hey i've got this timer working but now after two months when i ws goin thru my app i suddenly noticed the timer gets execute after 40 secs of delay than normal provided schedule time...means if in schedule method i pass 60000 milliseconds that is 1 min then it executes after 1 min and 40 secs...i dnt know why ...can anybody point out anythng i m missing....

Comment: You need to trace what is going on on your page, maybe you have some synchronous call which blocks JS execution for a while.